# Python appscript OSAX display_dialog: how to move it to foreground

Tags: python, sourceforge-appscript, py-appscript

I am playing around with the example from [here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc/osax-manual/03_examples.html); esp. I have this code:

```
from osax import *

sa = OSAX()

print sa.display_dialog("Python says hello!",
                        buttons=["Hi!", "Howdy!", "Duuuude!"],
                        default_button=3)
```

The dialog always opens in the background. How can I open it in (or move it to) the foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `activate` command to give your Python process the window manager application focus.

```
sa = OSAX()
sa.activate()
print sa.display_dialog(...)
```

You can also choose to not GUIfy your Python process by targeting a faceless background app as described [here](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc/osax-manual/04_notes.html).

Comment: This no longer works on 10.10 — the Python app doesn’t activate because it hasn’t been promoted to a foreground app, then `display_dialog` runs in the background.  However, targeting `OSAX()` or `ScriptingAddition()` to System Events (or another app of your choice) does work.  See http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/doc/osax-manual/04_notes.html for more.

Answer (score 0):

This works for now:

```
def go_foreground():
    from AppKit import NSApp, NSApplication
    NSApplication.sharedApplication()
    NSApp().activateIgnoringOtherApps_(True)
go_foreground()
```